# Question preview improvements

Tags: feature-request, markdown-preview

I think it's cool how you can hover over a user's question and get a small text sample of the question.

However, I never use it because of two reasons:

1. It takes too long to pop up.
2. It's a small box and the text is unformatted, making it difficult to read the question.

I would suggest that when you hover a question, a bigger, nicer popup comes up that shows the user's question properly formatted.

Would you find this feature useful?

Comment: I agree that the text is too small and it takes too long for the popup to occur but I would rather see effort put to making an essential like 'search' better - it is very primitive now - rather than some minor UI whistle (or are these bells?).

Comment: Of course it _can_ be done -- but then again, this website could show an image of Nyan Cat battling Darth Vader on every 1,00th page visit. A more appropriate question is "Would you find this feature useful?"

Comment: @jeff It's my first time on meta, I didn't really know how to word it. I just wanted to suggest a feature.

Comment: @skinnyTOD I fully agree the search needs to be improved. But I can get a great search with Google by typing my question in their search bar and then adding `site:stackoverflow.com` at the end -- I don't think anything can beat Google :)

Comment: @Hope4You: Programmers love workarounds and hacks (the *challenge* and all that). I prefer a well designed and implemented user interface.

Comment: How long it takes to pop up may vary by browser, but in Chrome it takes ~100-200ms to pop up; pretty much as fast as possible without it *randomly* popping up when you just happen to move your mouse over questions, which would be very annoying.